# What right did Rivka have to use Eisav's coat against him?

Tags: clothing, midrash, parashat-toldot, imahot-matriarch-mothers, shomrim-bailees

The *midrashim* bring that Rivka dressed up Yaakov in Eisav's special coat (originally given to Adam) that he used to serve his father. [See Rashi on 27:15 for partial source.]

Since Rivka was basically a *shomer chinam*, what right did she have to use Eisav's coat against him?

Comment: How did Eisav get the coat(rhetorical q) ?

Comment: @sam are you suggesting i write the full story in the question? are you hinting at an answer?

Comment: Answer.............

Comment: Need to find the source

Comment: @sam that answer is a *machlokes acharonim*, there is a strong opinion that stealing from a thief is forbidden.

Comment: @sam put in a rashi as a partial source

Comment: maybe tzafnas paneach (rogatchov) has something about this

Comment: Are there details to the legend that Eisvav took the coat when he killed Nimrod?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Isn't it a midrash ? (Not a "legend")